# Connection Reset error - SQL Server - MS JDBC Driver

Tags: sql-server-2016

We have a situation where this error only happens when connecting to our on-premise database, with a cloud runtime engine. This runtime is doing many database lookups and also excecuting insert and update commands, the runtime should be closing each connection automatically after the db command is successful.

"Failed to write JDBC target. Database Error: Connection reset"

One key factor for this matter is that we are able to run the "same" runtime  locallly and not have the Connection Reset errors. Also, this errror is intermittent. On some of our less complex runtimes, the cloud runtime is able to connect and execture db commands against the on-premise database without having connection resets crash the process. Based on this, I don't think it's a connectivity, firewall, or security issue.

From the research I've done, JBDC will not directly manage the connection pooling or call the sp_connection_reset stored procedure, rather the 3rd party Java EE in the runtime engine will be managing the connection pool.

I'm not necessarily looking for an answer here, as I realize I'm not a DBA and you will probably need more details to really dive in and solve this issue.

Rather, I'm trying to establish a baseline path and understanding for troubleshooting this issue.

My assumption is the connection pool is eventually reaching it's maximum number of connections allowed, and then the pooling mechanism will re-use previous connections in the pool that are not being used. It sounds like when that happens, the connection needs to be reset for integrity and security reasons.

If and when that happens, is that why our complex process is dying with this error in the middle of the process?

If so, I plan to focus in on what is different between the local and the cloud runtime engine configuration in regards to the maximum connections allowed and if and when it's re-using and resetting connections.

From what I read, it's not recommended to override this and set the connection reset flag to false, so it seems the answer will be to reduce the amount of db calls the runtime is making and/or increase the maximum connections allowed, so we don't get to the point where a connection needs to be re-used and therefore reset.

We do use these two params on our JBDC Driver configuration:

encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true

Is my fundamental direction here correct?  If not, please steer me in the right direction.

Thanks for your expertise,
Jon

Comment: This is likely a TCP/IP error bubbling up to the driver layer.  IE nothing at all to do with connection pooling or sp_reset_connection, except that connection pooling is keeping the JDBC connection object after the TCP connection has ended.  There may be a router or firewall device killing long-lived network connections, which isn't in the route when running on-prem.  Check if your Connection Pool can limit how long it retains connections.  Most of the perf gains from pooling results from almost-immediate reuse.

Comment: Thanks David, the cloud runtime I'm referring to is an IPAAS runtime engine. With the scenario of the runtime in the cloud and the SQL Server database on-premise, is the below statement correct, I want to make sure I understand where the pooling configuration would be performed. "Although the JDBC driver supports Java EE connection pooling, it does not provide its own pooling implementation. The driver relies on third-party Java Application Servers to manage the connections."

Comment: Pooling is a feature of your Java EE runtime.  The Microsoft JDBC driver just implements a set of interfaces that enable it to plug-in to a third-party connection pooling implementation.

Comment: Thanks again David. I could use some clarification here. It sounds like reducing how long the connection pool retains connections could possibly avoid the connection reset error that is masking the actual TCP error. Is that what you're getting at here?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, and has little downside (if you can figure out how to implement it).

Comment: We did find a difference in the SQL Traces when comparing the Cloud Agent's inserts into the database vs the Local Agent's inserts. The Local Agent uses 'sp_prepexec' for all table inserts, and 'sp_execute' if there is a second row inserted for the same table. The Cloud Agent uses 'sp_executesql' for all table inserts, and 'sp_prepexec' if these is a second row inserted into the same table. When this second row insert is attempted for the Cloud Agent, the SQL Trace has a Prepare SQL, RPC Completed, and Audit Logout after this 2nd row is attempted and the JDBC reports a Connection Reset error.